# Return Error in modal instead of Redirect C# MVC Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

When a user selects something they do not have access to or goes to a page they do not have access to it redirects them to a page that says they do not have access. I would like to handle this in a different manner. By using a Modal instead of the redirect.

This is controlled in a

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
```

So when a user goes to a page that they do not have access to it redirects

```
UnAuthoRedirect(context);
```

This is the UnAuthRedirect

```
    private void UnAuthoRedirect(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(Url.Action("unauthorized", "Account"));
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Error/AdminStatus");

    }
```

I also have Ajax calls on buttons

```
 @Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Addresses", "Edit", "btn btn-warning btn-sm", new { id = item.AddressUI })
```

When a user selects a Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink and they do not have permission to access it, A modal pops up with  "Ajax call failed" I would like it to say a custom error.

I have tried this:

```
if (IsThisAjaxRequest() == true)//if userid !=null && Check Crud
  {
    //Equals("You do not have permission to this area");
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

  }
```

But the outcome is the same.

Here is the IsThisAjaxRequest()

```
    private bool IsThisAjaxRequest()
    {
        bool result = false;
        var currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        if (currentContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != null
            && currentContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

So if i could customize both of these to just popup the same error that would be best, If not then i will do what is necessary.

If you need to see anything else just let me know. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Added ModalDialogExtensions

```
   public static class ModalDialogExtensions
{
    sealed class DialogActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        public DialogActionResult(string message)
        {
            Message = message ?? string.Empty;
        }

        string Message { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {

            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<script>   window.location.assign('" + Message + "')   </script>");
        }
    }



    public static MvcHtmlString ModalDialogActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string dialogTitle, string CssClass)
    {
        var dialogDivId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValues: null,
                ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = dialogDivId,
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    OnBegin = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "prepareModalDialog('{0}')", dialogDivId),
                    OnFailure = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "clearModalDialog('{0}');alert('Ajax call failed')", dialogDivId),
                    OnSuccess = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "openModalDialog('{0}', '{1}')", dialogDivId, dialogTitle)
                }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = CssClass });

    }
```

UPDATE:

I realized that the only reason that the link would fail is if they did not have access to it. So I simply replaced the text of the above "OnFailure" to

```
OnFailure = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "clearModalDialog('{0}');alert('You are not authorized to access this area!')", dialogDivId)
```

However i am still wanting to use a modal popup for the UnAuthorized instead of a redirect. Any suggestions would be helpful..

UPDATE:
From what i have read in some other posts is that you would do a redirect. I have also read that you should avoid redirects in an MVC solution. So I am not sure what is right and what is wrong..

Comment: First, I'm fairly certain@Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink is not a proper overload. Maybe a simple check, but since you are using the @Ajax.ActionLink helper (I'm assuming this is the helper you were referring to), are you sure that you included the unobtrusive ajax script file reference in your view?

Comment: ModalDialogActionLink is a custom extension. I did not write it. I had some people working on my site. All it does is bring up the form or view in a Ajax Modal. There is not a reference or ajax code on the view. What is being used in the Class is "System.Web.MVC.Ajax". I will post what is in this class above with one of the instances. It is long so i do not want to post all of them.

Comment: I suppose i may try just changing the Response.Write but i do not want to add a custom error in this because if there is a different error then it should give the proper error. So maybe play off of that with a custom error for the UnAuthorized?

Comment: That could work. What I am familiar with is utilizing unobtrusive Ajax, where you could have controller side logic to route display a partial view on your main view page if they have access, if not, display a standardized partial view that states unauthorized access. Without knowing your app's authentication method and validation, I wouldn't be able to give you a precise solution.

Comment: The authorization for the site is EntityFramework Identity. However when displaying the menu and authorized areas, it goes through a BaseController to check to see if the person has authority or not through a permissions table on the Controller and Action. I am going to try what i just did and i will post if it works or not.